# Search system with multiple tables on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a symptom checker system where the user inserts a list of symptoms (1 to 5) and the site shows a list of all illnesses that have those symptoms.

The database is as such: `illness`, `symptom` and `symptom_illness` tables. `symptom_illness` links the other two so each symptom can belong to many illnesses and illnesses can have many symptoms.

I understand the logic of it and have a rough SQL query done but I would like to know how to implement this search system (preferably one that doesn't use an explicit query like the one I have).

Comment: What kind of search system do you want? If you set up a `has_many :through` relationship going both ways between `illnesses` and `symptoms`, it will be as simple as `Illness.find(23).symptoms` to give you every `Symptom` belonging to the `Illness` with the `id` of `23` and `Symptom.find(34).illnesses` to give you every `Illness` belonging to the `Symptom` with the `id` of `34`.

Comment: This does make sense but I'm not sure on how to show the results of the find method as I'm quite new to Rails. 
In this case, I want to provide a symptom id and receive the list of illnesses so I'm using the `Symptom.find(id).illnesses` one

Comment: That method will return a collection that you can use the `each` method on. Have you gone through any tutorial(s) or guide(s) on Ruby yet?

Comment: Yes, I've done most of Michael Hartl's tutorial. I figured it out not too long ago, turns out I was using the wrong syntax to print out the names themselves. Thank you

Comment: (May be unrelated to this question) My problem now is how to make the variable for the find method something provided by the user instead of a static number, which I am unsure of how to do

Comment: You want the user to provide a symptom and you'll tell them what illness(es) are associated it? You can use a form. Forms aren't always for submitting new records. Look in to [form tags](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-basic-forms) You can also do something simpler like a select list, where each option is a dynamically generated link. There are tons of possibilities for how your view can send information to your controller actions. Get creative, but keep it clean and organized like Hartl does with human-readable variables and functions and intuitive, clear logic.